# Intern Promise Timeouts

Tags: intern

I am writing some functional tests with Intern and came across the following section of text...

"The test will also fail if the promise is not fulfilled within the timeout of the test (the default is 30 seconds; set this.timeout to change the value)."

at...

https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Writing-Tests-with-Intern#asynchronous-testing

How do I set the promise timeout for functional tests? I have tried calling timeout() directly on the promise but it isn't a valid method.

I have already set the various WD timeout (page load timeout, implicit wait etc...) but I am having issues with promises timing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the timeout in my tests via the suggested API's just didn't work.
Its far from ideal but I ended up modifying Test.js directly and hard coding in the timeout I wnated.
I did notice when looking through the source that there was a comment on the timeout code saying something like // TODO timeouts not working correctly yet

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working okay on the latest version:

```
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'require',
    'intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil'
], function (registerSuite, assert, require, pollUntil) {
    registerSuite(function(){
        return {
            name: 'index',

            setup: function() {         
            },

            'Test timeout': function () {           
                this.timeout = 90000;
                return this.remote.sleep(45000);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add `defaultTimeout: 90000` to your configuration file (`tests/intern.js` in the default tutorial codebase) to globally set the timeout. This works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

A timeout for a test is either set by passing the timeout as the first argument to `this.async`, or by setting `this.timeout` (it is a property, not a method).

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me at all. Setting the value seemed to have absolutely no effect. Its not great but I ended up resorting to modifying teh test.js class directly and setting the timeout value in there. This worked for me but is obviously not the best approach

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who found their way here while using InternJS 4 and utilizing `async`/`await` for functional testing: `timeout` and `executeAsync` just wouldn't work for me, but the pattern below did. Basically I just executed some logic and used the `sleep` method at a longer interval than the `setTimeout`. Keep in mind that the `javascript` run inside of `execute` is block scoped so you will want to cache anything you want to reference later on the `window` object. Hopefully this saves someone else some time and frustration...

```
test(`timer test`, async ({remote}) => {
    await remote.execute(`
        // run setup logic, keep in mind this is scoped and if you want to reference anything it should be window scoped
        window.val = "foo";
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            window.val = "bar";
        }, 50);
        return true;
    `);
    await remote.sleep(51); // remote will chill for 51 ms
    let data = await remote.execute(`
        // now you can call the reference and the timeout has run
        return window.val;
    `);
    assert.strictEqual(
      data,
      'bar',
      `remote.sleep(51) should wait until the setTimeout has run, converting window.val from "foo" to "bar"`
    );
});
```